# Persisting property values in a POM on a release

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project that builds a plugin for a third-party system. The third party system *requires* version numbers to be in the format: `YYYYMMDDNN` where `NN` is a build number, and the date should correspond to the release date of the project. We'll call this the "external version". At build time, we use the `maven.build.timestamp` to set this value, and the `maven-release-plugin` to filter this value into our sources appropriately.

We also have an internal semantic versioning number scheme, which we use for the `${project.version}`.

When we do a release, the maven-release-plugin appropriately transforms the `project.version` to remove SNAPSHOT, tags it in git, and so on. Is there a way to also "fix" the `YYYYMMDDNN` version in the at the same time, so that future builds of that release are identical?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the release plugin's `preparationGoals` to edit the `pom.xml` locking down the property, and then use `completionGoals` to unlock it afterwards.

The changes you make in those goals will be committed, and in fact an aim of mine is to provide a goal on the versions maven plugin to lock down ranges and unlock them again for use in the above two steps so that version ranges become almost useable... Just avent had the time, but I did add the completion goals release phase.